# How to make RTL appBarConfiguration androidx.navigation?

Tags: android, navigation, fragment, android-appbarlayout

I want make RTL appBarConfiguration. and this is my code for MainActivity. is there any way that help me to do this without use custom toolbar or make some custom things?
I search and found this is android document : [navigation-ui][1]
but I look for something simple like layout direction if something like this is it available

MainActivity class:

```
    private lateinit var drawerLayout: DrawerLayout
    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val binding =
            DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityMainBinding>(this, R.layout.activity_main)
        drawerLayout = binding.drawerLayout

        val navController = this.findNavController(R.id.navHostFragment)
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph, drawerLayout)
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, drawerLayout)

        navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { nc: NavController, nd: NavDestination, _: Bundle? ->
            if (nd.id == nc.graph.startDestination) {
                drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED)
            } else {
                drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED)
            }
        }

        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.navView, navController)
    }



    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navigationController = findNavController(R.id.navHostFragment)
        return navigationController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }


    override fun onBackPressed() {
        if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        } else {
            return super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }
}
```

and here activity_main.xml:

````
<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

    </data>

<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navHostFragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation"/>


    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/fragment_cart"
        />



</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
</layout>```

[![now it's look like this:][2]][2]

I wanna hamberger menu place in right and that three icon place in left


  [1]: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#kotlin
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOur8.png
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can fix it by adding this section in activity_main.xml and MainActivity.kt

activity_main.xml

````
<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

    </data>

<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navHostFragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/fragment_cart"
        />



</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
</layout> ```

MainActivity.kt:

``` class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var drawerLayout: DrawerLayout
    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
    private lateinit var toolbar: androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val binding =
            DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityMainBinding>(this, R.layout.activity_main)
        drawerLayout = binding.drawerLayout
        toolbar = binding.toolbar


        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        //supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        //supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)

        val navController = this.findNavController(R.id.navHostFragment)
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph, drawerLayout)
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, drawerLayout)

        navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { nc: NavController, nd: NavDestination, _: Bundle? ->
            if (nd.id == nc.graph.startDestination) {
                drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED)
            } else {
                drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED)
            }
        }

        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.navView, navController)
    }



    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navigationController = findNavController(R.id.navHostFragment)
        return navigationController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }


    override fun onBackPressed() {
        if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        } else {
            return super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }
} ```

I hope this help someone.
````